# how to merge two branches where 1st has one commit A and 2nd has commit A amended to B and 3 commits over top of B? Without a merge commit

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have two branches

branch_a -> `-x-x-x-x-x-A-C-D-E` ( <- A-C-D-E are the latest commit on branch_a)

branch_b -> `-x-x-x-x-x-B(A-amended)` ( <- B is the commit which is amended version of A , that has few more changes as compared to A)

I want to

```
branch_a -> -x-x-x-x-A-C-D-E                 
                     \           ->(TARGET_branch=)  -x-x-x-x-x-B-C-D-E ( I know that as B is changed commit id of C,D,E may also change and they will become (e.g.) F-G-H , that is accepted just dont wanna lose the individuality of the commit.
branch_b ->-x-x-x-x-x-B-
```

**All of this should be done without any merge commit and without loosing any of the commits**

One possible solution to me is take diff of B and A , go to branch_a and do `git rebase -i HEAD~4`, amend commit A with changes from B and then continue the rebase.

Now that is a very crude way to do it.

well we will have to resolve the merge conflicts somewhere, but it surely can be made much simpler.
Does anybody know of any simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a `rebase --onto`, in order to select only the commit you want.
That would change branch B, you can then reset A to B:

```
git switch branch_b
git rebase --onto B A branch_a
```

Only C,D,E will be rebased on top of B.